# Place jQuery var into <a> </a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I creating at this time a form that should get the name of the user in a jQuery var and add it to the steps that I made.

Here are my steps for the form and the input where I collect the "username":

```html
<div class="stepwizard row col-md-12">

  <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-1" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Hey there!</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-2" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Information</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-3" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-store"></i> Store</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-4" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-bicycle"></i> Bicycle</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-5" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-user-shield"></i> Insurance</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-6" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-user-shield"></i> Shipment</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
  <input maxlength="100" id="userfirstname" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" type="text">
</div>
```

and here is my jQuery that collect the data from my input textfield:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userfirstname= $('#userfirstname').val();
});
```

How can I place the variable's string in the HTML:

```html
<div class="stepwizard-step">
    <a href="#step-2" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i> "here place the var" Information</a>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to add value inside anchor tag then take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148432/how-to-add-a-certain-value-to-anchor-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert variable value inside html with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621495/insert-variable-value-inside-html-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-2" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> <div id="user"></div> Information</a>
</div>

<script>
    $("#user").html(userfirstname);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can always an element with jQuery's selection tool. Here you could select your link by it's href value: `$("a[href$='#step-6']")`.

Then use the `.text()` method to change it's content:

```
const element = $("a[href$='#step-6']");
element.text('some text' + element.text())
```

Or in your case:

```
const element = $("a[href$='#step-6']");
element.text(userfirstname + element.text()) // assuming userfirstname is set
```

Here is the demo code:

```js
const element = $("a[href$='#step-6']");

element.text('some text' + element.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stepwizard row col-md-12">

  <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-1" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Hey there!</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-2" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Information</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-3" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-store"></i> Store</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-4" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-bicycle"></i> Bicycle</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-5" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-user-shield"></i> Insurance</a>
    </div>

    <div class="stepwizard-step">
      <a href="#step-6" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-user-shield"></i> Shipment</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
  <input maxlength="100" id="userfirstname" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: so it will place the text after the </i> ?

Comment: it seems that my jQuery dont work.

$(document).ready(function () {
 var userfirstname= $('#username').val();
});

what do i wrong? i dont understand why the var is empty

Comment: like the code before i got as result:
[object HTMLInputElement] Shipment

Comment: Where is your element `#username`?

Comment: <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input maxlength="100" id="userfirstname" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" type="text">
          </div>

Comment: This is not the element `#username`, what is the HTML element that has the id name `#username`?

Comment: i want to have the id #username linked to the input, to collect it directly. Is this prossible if i change the id fom userfirstname to username ?

Comment: Please explain in detail what you would like to achieve, I don't understand.